# Handle null values in a logic app with JSON table and compose object

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Azure Alert triggers an Logic App for output to for example Microsoft Teams
Common Alert Schema
JSON input to the logic app.

The JSON table has columns and rows

Its easy enough to compose an object with fixed value in the array see example below.

However this fails when any value is null. Which brings me to the crux.
I should be able to dynamically create the table with the information available. I feel limited in what i can do with a logic app. With powershell i would've probably solved this with a hashtable.

I've tried iterating through both row and column and appending to an array. However the data gets goes all over the place which is logical.

I suppose I need to iterate through and compose and object somehow but then I just overwrite the object with each iteration

Working example with fixed values

```
Variable Math
item()[2]

Variable Number
if(contains('56789', substring(string(variables('math')),4,1)),substring(string(add(variables('math'),0.01)),0,4),substring(string(variables('math')),0,4))

Compose Object
{

"AggregatedValue": @{variables('Number')},

"Computer": "@{item()[0]}    ",

"TimeGenerated": "@{item()[1]}"

}
```

I get the following table to work with

```
[
  {
    "name": "PrimaryResult",
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "Computer",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "TimeGenerated",
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      {
        "name": "AggregatedValue",
        "type": "real"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      [
        "server.example.org",
        "2019-10-30T08:44:48Z",
        2.409970182797006
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

JSON Schema

```
{
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "properties": {
        "alertContext": {
          "properties": {
            "AffectedConfigurationItems": {
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "type": "array"
            },
            "AlertType": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "IncludedSearchResults": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "LinkToSearchResults": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Operator": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "ResultCount": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "SearchIntervalDurationMin": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "SearchIntervalEndtimeUtc": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "SearchIntervalInMinutes": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "SearchIntervalStartTimeUtc": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "SearchQuery": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "SearchResults": {
              "properties": {
                "dataSources": {
                  "items": {
                    "properties": {
                      "resourceId": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "tables": {
                        "items": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "resourceId",
                      "tables"
                    ],
                    "type": "object"
                  },
                  "type": "array"
                },
                "tables": {
                  "items": {
                    "properties": {
                      "columns": {
                        "items": {
                          "properties": {
                            "name": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": {
                              "type": "string"
                            }
                          },
                          "required": [
                            "name",
                            "type"
                          ],
                          "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                      },
                      "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "rows": {
                        "items": {
                          "type": "array"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                      }
                    },
                    "required": [
                      "name",
                      "columns",
                      "rows"
                    ],
                    "type": "object"
                  },
                  "type": "array"
                }
              },
              "type": "object"
            },
            "SeverityDescription": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Threshold": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "WorkspaceId": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "type": "object"
        },
        "essentials": {
          "properties": {
            "alertContextVersion": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "alertId": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "alertRule": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "alertTargetIDs": {
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "type": "array"
            },
            "description": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "essentialsVersion": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "firedDateTime": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "monitorCondition": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "monitoringService": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "originAlertId": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "severity": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "signalType": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "type": "object"
        }
      },
      "type": "object"
    },
    "schemaId": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

Expected Output

```
All values not null
computer        Timegenerated       AggregatedValue
server.example.org  2019-10-30T08:44:48Z    2.41
```

```
Two values null
computer        Timegenerated       AggregatedValue
server.example.org
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not so clear about what you want ? Could you please tell us your requirements and I will help you solve it ? Currently, per my understanding, if you don't want the null value in the result, do you mind add a "If" condition in you logic app to judge if the value is null. For example if variables['Number'] not null, then do the compose, otherwise variables[Number] = "0.00" and do the compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use logic app to handle this data, you have to add some actions to handle the errors. I use `Parse JSON` to mock receiving table data.

I init the variable `Timegenerated` and set it with the value in the table and set it with space while the last action failed.

[image]

[image]

And then init the `math` same as the `Timegenerated`. One more step is init the variable `Number` with `if(contains('56789', substring(string(variables('math')),4,1)),substring(string(add(float(variables('math')),0.01)),0,4),substring(string(variables('math')),0,4))` and set it run after last action is skipped.

[image]

[image]

At last, do the compose action, one with variable `math` run after init variable Number is skipped and one with variable `Number`.

[image]

[image]

And if you think that this is too cumbersome, you could choose to use azure function to handle this data. The [azure function support powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-powershell), also you could [call Azure Function in the logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#add-existing-functions-to-logic-apps) to process your table data to function, in the powershell function handle it then return it to logic app, then you will be able to get the data you want in the logic app.

Comment: Thanks for this. However doesn't this method assume that the values are static?
I mean item[1] might be TimeGenerated but no necessary. I think I'll explore the azure function route to see if I can make that work better.

Thanks :)

Comment: No, it doesn't. cause it's an array if it's not static and change the property every time it will return an error cause the index could be out of range. If that, maybe the function is the best, you also could use c# or other language .

Comment: @a.pof, if this could help you, please accept it as the answer. Thanks!